# Настройка сетевого принтера через Ethernet при работающем Wi-Fi

Tags: windows, сеть, ip, администрирование, dhcp

Добрый день. Есть офис с 5тью компьютерами ( win 8 и 8.1 ) и 2мя принтерами и wifi роутером от MTC. Смысл в том, что при настройке сетевого принтера через ethernet, отваливается wifi. А при настройке через wifi, роутер не умеет делать DHCP-сервер в ручном режиме и не позволяет прикрепить по MAC адресу, за каждым пк конкретный IP. Таким образом при загрузке компов ip меняется у хоста принтер драйвера и остальные не могут к нему обращаться. Плюс ко всему там еще и несколько телефонов которые тоже получают ip у роутера. Приходится каждый день прописывать ip адрес компьютеров-хостов.

Как можно выйти из этой ситуации без покупки нового роутера?

Может можно как-то настроить внутреннюю сеть через ethernet, а и интервент через wifi, так, чтобы оно друг друга не душило ( когда настраиваешь кабель, то на wifi пишет "ограничено" )

Comment: Нарисуйте схему сетки. Из описания ничего не понятно, что куда включено.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то у вас имеются две физически несвязанные сети. Одна - это проводная, на отдельном коммутаторе, никак на связанная с роутером. Вторая - беспроводная, "завязанная" на роутер с доступом в Интернет.

Тогда вариант решения следующий. Оставляем настройки беспроводной сети неизменными (то есть, в вашем случае, получение адреса с DHCP-сервера роутера), а для проводной сети настраиваем адреса вручную (компьютеров немного, вполне можно). Для того, чтобы избежать конфликта адресов, выбирать адреса нужно из другого диапазона. Например, если роутер выдаёт подсеть `192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0`, для проводной сети выбираем подсеть `192.168.2.0/255.255.255.0`. В настройках проводной сети шлюз по умолчанию и адреса DNS-серверов не указываем. Далее даём принтеру адрес из той же самой проводной сети и настраиваем к принтеру доступ по этому адресу.

Comment: я примерно, как вы описываете и делаю. wifi ip адреса раздает DHCP сервер роутера. Адреса в диапазоне от 192.168.8.100- 199, а для проводной сети задаю в ручную, пробывал разные адреса и разные подсети. и все равно конфликт. Как только езернет оказывается в компьютере, так wifi не работает.  Может быть такое, что в ноутбуке сетевая не может в двух режимах работать?

Comment: Это крайне маловероятно. Сетевых карт там две и они могут работать одновременно. Приведите пример ваших адресов и масок подсетей для двух сетевых подключений одного компьютера. Может быть, что-то не так делаете?